# How to debug an overloading backboardd?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, instruments

I have a `UIView` with several instances of a subclassed `CAShapeLayer` added as sublayers to its layer property.

I am animating changes to the `UIBezierPath` for each of these layers, which looks awesome and is performant, **but hits ~90% CPU on the `backboardd` process** when I run it through **Activity Monitor** in Instruments.

How can I get more information about what's happening here? `backboardd` is the behind-the-scenes rendering of Core Graphics / Core Animation stuff on the GPU, right? Is there support for further debugging in Instruments somewhere? Could I do something fancy with **GCD** to load `backboardd` less?

**EDIT:** After escalating this to a TSI with Apple, they have confirmed that this is 'expected behavior' for this number of animated CAShapeLayers. Sigh. They did offer a suggestion [at this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1673/_index.html), which involves continually pausing and unpausing the animation to mimic a lower frame rate. (Since it's the calculations for each DisplayLink-locked animation frame that are slamming `backboardd`)

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer {

    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    layer.speed = 0.0;
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}

-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer {

    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
    layer.speed = 1.0;
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    layer.beginTime = 0.0;
    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}
```

Finally, the nice Apple tech pointed out that animation framerate control "would make a decent API enhancement request, as an aside" — so I'm making one, **[and you should, too](https://bugreport.apple.com/)**. :)

Comment: Since CALayers are based on OpenGL, could you use the OpenGL ES Analysis tool? I know it integrates well with your own OpenGL ES source code, but I don’t know if it would tell you anything about system OpenGL ES operations.

Comment: Thanks Zev, I've tried that but didn't get anything really useful. The tool basically says "you are using a lot of graphics processing" but neither the tool nor the docs have a lot to say regarding optimizing my code. I have filed a TSI with Apple and will post back if I learn anything there.

Comment: If you’re using shadows, set the shadowPath [like this](http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/on-the-importance-of-setting-shadowpath/). The article also details using the CoreAnimation Instrument.

Comment: Note that the animations are all on the CAShapeLayer, not on the UIView, which is only a container. But, good article!

Comment: Did you end up using the stop-n-go manual framerate control? We’re running into the same opaque backboardd crashes while scrolling a complex stock-price chart…

Answer (score 1):

You need to try and isolate your problem. It sounds like your layer hierarchy isn't scaling well and is becoming too complicated.

Do you see the same CPU activity if you use less instances of the subclassed CAShapeLayer? Or if you try to perform less animations?