# 'backboardd' with high CPU usage percentage on iPhone4 of iOS6.0 while using opengles

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cpu-usage

honestly wish your help!

Using OpenGLES2.0 **on iPhone4 with iOS6.1.2**, the CPU usage of '**backboardd**' is up to about **17%** , while running my application with **35%** CPU usage to render video frames up to about 5~8fps. (**I wish to use up to 50% to have high fps**)

Here is more infos if matters: 
1)on my iPhone4 with iOS5, the fps is higher of 10fps.
2)on iPhone5, 'backboard' eats about 7% CPU.

Is there anything to be optimize in my application to avoid the high CPU usage on my iPhone4 with iOS6.0.

I've search 'backboard', it's a daemon that runs alongside the SpringBoard daemon.http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Backboardd

Here is some similar problems of 'backboard' on iOS6.

[How to debug an overloading backboardd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588748/how-to-debug-an-overloading-backboardd)

[How to synchronize OpenGL drawing with UIKit updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967340/how-to-synchronize-opengl-drawing-with-uikit-updates)

Thanks for you reading, any advice welcomes.

Comment: How are you rendering these video frames? Are you using Core Graphics at any point in this? You haven't provided a lot of detail here.

Comment: The original format is YUV data, so I create three textures by glTexImage2D, and updates the data by glTexSubImage2D each frame.

Comment: Was there a solution to the problem? Seems like I'm running into the same problem. I have a OpenGL ES 2 render loop setup that does nothing but make a call to glClear(). This call causes the `backboardd` to slow down any additional processing done in background thread (GCD, pthread doesn't matter).